# Replacing button_to with dynamic Select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I am complete beginner with forms, just trying to tame it but hopeless atm.

I have this following button_to setup:

```
<% @product.variants.each do |variant| %>
    <div><%= variant.asin %></div>
    <div><%= variant.price %></div>
    <div><%= button_to "Add to cart", shopping_cart_path(:variant_id => variant) %></div>
<% end %>
```

This works quite fine, the problem with it is, it creates a several buttons for each product.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to have only one button and select, as shown below. Which directions do I need to take to pass this hash dynamically.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [select_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) and use it nested inside a [form_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag). You will have a `form` containing a `select` tag inside.

Your code should look similar to this:

```
<%= form_tag shopping_cart_path do %>
  <%= select_tag('variant', options_from_collection_for_select(@product.variants, "id", "asin")) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Note: The code above is not tested, but it should give you an idea on how you should approach this.

Comment: thanks @florin-ionce ,this gave me some tips.
Any clue about how can I pass this (:variant_id => variant) with form_tag?

Comment: @nacon I think it should work like this `<%= select_tag('variant_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@product.variants, "id", "asin")) %>`

Comment: thanks @florin-ionce, it worked as you said. You saved my day!